# Positioning A Video Camera In HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have successfully moved this video camera that I have written in HTML to the right, so that it is in the center of the form, but would like to know how I can find the exact center of the form by finding the total width an dividing it by two in CSS. Any ideas on how I can get the full size of the width of the form?

The following is the source code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Webcam</title>

    <style>
    div.video-wrap
    {
        position: relative;
        left: 450px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Image Recognition Login</h2>

<div class="video-wrap">
    <video id="video" playsinline autoplay></video>
</div>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <p>Click the following <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span> 
        button to take a facial image of yourself (be sure to look straight into the camera):</p>    
    <p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span> Camera
    </a>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="controller">
    <button id="snap">Capture</button>
</div>

<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>

<script>

'use strict';

const video = document.getElementById('video');
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const snap = document.getElementById('snap');
const errorMsgElement = document.getElementById('spanErrorMsg');

const constraints =
{
    audio: true,
    video:
    {
        width: 1280, height: 550
    }
};

async function init()
{
    try
    {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
        handleSuccess(stream);
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `navigator.getUserMedia.error:${e.toString()}`;
    }
}

function handleSuccess(stream)
{
    window.stream = stream;
    video.srcObject = stream;
}

init();


var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
snap.addEventListener("click", function()
{
    // drawImage(image, xCoordinate, yCoordinate, recWidth, recHeight)
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a second class (or better, an id) to the div, then use css on that class/id to move it

Comment: Hi, I managed to center it, but would like to know how to get the full size of the width of the form?

Comment: This article should help you get the width of the element: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/javascript-width-height/